# Pytest running a certain test suite in a certain thread

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

The requirement is to run all the tests belonging to a suite in a certain thread.
For example having suite1, suite2, suite3 and so on.
And I'd like to make all the tests belonging to the suite1 executed in one thread(thread1), whereas tests belonging to the suite2 in another thread(thread2) and tests from suite3 in one more separate thread(thread3).

As per [xdist](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-xdist/#parallelization)  there are only 2 options:
 - --dist=loadscope(by module)
 - --dist=loadfile(by filename)

It would be exactly what I need to have kind of a --dist=loaddirectory, to grab all the tests in a certain directory(e.g for each dir in a dir given as a path to all the test suits)

For sure I can try to launch pytest several times each time passing a suite directory, but afraid it would have bad consequences for performance as in this case there are several instances of the pytest running rather than several threads.

So could anybody please advise if you are familiar with something that can help to tackle the requirements?

Any help or ideas, or even directions to dig are much appreciated.

Comment: Update, I've just discovered that xdist doesn't use threads :( https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist/issues/409

Comment: Besides of `xdist`, I know of [`pytest-parallel`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-parallel/) and [`pytest-concurrent`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-concurrent/) that claim to parallelize the test execution; however, I suppose your requirement of grouping the tests by directory is somewhat specific, so you will have to implement the missing bits yourself.

Comment: Thanks @hoefling, yep, we have to implement it on our own. However for now we've stopped at decision to use xdist with  --dist=loadfile scope.

Comment: If you stick with `xdist`, the grouping by directory should be a straightfoward task to implement - you need a custom scheduler that splits the nodeid by the directory and not by file. Take the [`LoadFileScheduling`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist/blob/master/xdist/scheduler/loadfile.py) as the example.